# "Perspective" ou "Perspectif"?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, orthographe

For a translation of English "Perspective". Google Translate says "Perspective"  but my previous experience in French says that English words ending with "ive" end with "if" in French. I tried Google searching "Perspectif" and got some dictionary results, but they also mention "Perspective".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rule is for French adjectives that end with *-if* at the masculine to end with *-ive* at the feminine, e.g..

*actif / active

affirmatif / affirmative

aggressif / aggressive

décisif / décisive*
...

On the other hand, nouns in *-if/-ive*, often substantivated adjectives, generally exists with a single gender and their ending match it, e.g.:

*Un adjectif

Un adhésif

Un apéritif

Un canif<sup>1</sup>

Un explosif

Un motif<sup>1</sup>

Un récif<sup>1</sup>*
...
*Une archive<sup>1</sup>

Une coopérative

Une directive

Une incisive

Une initiative<sup>1</sup>

Une lessive<sup>1</sup>

Une locomotive<sup>1</sup>

Une perspective

Une rétrospective*

Some nouns (referring to persons) exist with both genders:

*Un sportif/une sportive

Un fugitif/une fugitive

Un juif/une juive*

There is also *un esquif/une esquive* where the nouns have an unrelated etymology and different meanings.

Finally, there are very few gender/ending mismatches:

*Un convive<sup>1</sup>

Un détective<sup>1</sup>

Une manif<sup>1</sup>* (here just because it is a short form of *une manifestation*)

*Détective* is likely masculine simply because it was borrowed "as is" from English and there was only male detective at that time. Nowadays, it is definitely possible to say *une détective* when talking about a woman.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Nouns not derived from an adjective.</sub>